# EFS does not persist any data

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I have a Fargate container with an access point configured to use AWS' EFS. The volume seems to mount properly, but data written into it does not persist.

- No matter how much data I put into the drive, it remains with only `6.00 KiB` total size.
- I can confirm the volume is mounted properly as changes in the `posixUser` of the access point change the ownership of the folder inside the container accordingly.

Thus, **the container can read and mount the filesystem, but writing to the the mounted volume does not affect the EFS volume.**

I have tried toggling encryption, modifying user, change task and execution roles, and I have permission to ports 2049 and 22. I also have spent the last 5 days reading the logs of my containers and redeploying over and over again. I am absolutely hopeless by now and any help would be appreciated ❤️

Code snippet: https://gist.github.com/zvictor/eedb2b5ca6756cd05e5def9081a4442e

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib'
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2'
import * as ecs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs'
import * as efs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-efs'
import * as logs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-logs'

export class BaseStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, environment: Record<string, string>, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props)

    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, `${id}-Vpc`, {
      natGateways: 0,
      maxAzs: 2,
      enableDnsHostnames: true,
      enableDnsSupport: true,
    })

    const securityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, `${id}-security-group`, {
      vpc,
      allowAllOutbound: true,
    })

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, `${id}-Cluster`, {
      vpc,
    })

    const fileSystem = new efs.FileSystem(this, `${id}-FileSystem`, {
      vpc,
      encrypted: true,
      performanceMode: efs.PerformanceMode.MAX_IO,
      lifecyclePolicy: efs.LifecyclePolicy.AFTER_7_DAYS,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
    })

    fileSystem.connections.addSecurityGroup(securityGroup)
    fileSystem.connections.allowInternally(ec2.Port.tcp(22))
    fileSystem.connections.allowInternally(ec2.Port.tcp(2049))

    const accessPoint = new efs.AccessPoint(this, `${id}-AccessPoint`, {
      fileSystem,
      path: '/data',
      createAcl: {
        ownerGid: '999', // user created in Dockerfile
        ownerUid: '999', // user created in Dockerfile
        permissions: '777',
      },
      posixUser: {
        uid: '999', // user created in Dockerfile
        gid: '999', // user created in Dockerfile
      },
    })

    const volumeName = 'efs-data'

    const image = ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset('../services/whatsapp-listener', {
      file: './deployment/Dockerfile',
    })

    const taskDefinition = new ecs.TaskDefinition(this, `${id}-TaskDefinition`, {
      family: `${id}-TaskDefinition`,
      memoryMiB: `512`,
      cpu: `256`,
      compatibility: ecs.Compatibility.EC2_AND_FARGATE,
      networkMode: ecs.NetworkMode.AWS_VPC,
    })

    taskDefinition.addVolume({
      name: volumeName,
      efsVolumeConfiguration: {
        fileSystemId: fileSystem.fileSystemId,
        transitEncryption: 'ENABLED',
        authorizationConfig: {
          accessPointId: accessPoint.accessPointId,
        },
      },
    })

    const logGroup = new logs.LogGroup(this, `${id}-ContainerLogGroup`, {
      logGroupName: `${id}-LogGroup`,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      retention: logs.RetentionDays.ONE_WEEK,
    })

    const logging = new ecs.AwsLogDriver({
      logGroup,
      streamPrefix: id,
      mode: ecs.AwsLogDriverMode.NON_BLOCKING,
    })

    const container = taskDefinition.addContainer(`${id}-Container`, {
      image,
      memoryLimitMiB: 512,
      cpu: 256,
      logging,
      environment,
    })

    container.addMountPoints({
      containerPath: '/data',
      sourceVolume: volumeName,
      readOnly: false,
    })

    const service = new ecs.FargateService(this, `${id}-Service`, {
      enableExecuteCommand: true,
      taskDefinition,
      desiredCount: 1,
      cluster,
      vpcSubnets: { subnets: vpc.publicSubnets },
      securityGroups: [securityGroup],
      capacityProviderStrategies: [
        {
          capacityProvider: 'FARGATE_SPOT',
          weight: 100,
          base: 1,
        },
        {
          capacityProvider: 'FARGATE',
          weight: 1,
        },
      ],
      assignPublicIp: true,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the container using the volume? Are you sure it's writing to EFS?

Comment: You are mounting to the `/data` path inside the container. What are you writing to the `/data` path when the container is running? You could use `aws ecs exec` to verify what is being written to the `/data` path https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html Also, if you are just looking at the EFS web console to determine the size of your EFS volume, I'm pretty sure that only updates once every hour or so.

Comment: Yes @gshpychka, it is! Without the access point set (it should be mounted at `/data`) the application fails with `EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/data/session-z001-Jesus'`.

However if I change the `containerPath` to something else with permission access by the user (e.g. `/home/pptruser/data`) and update the app accordingly, then:
1. everything works fine without the access point
2. it fails with the access point 

I have no doubts that the volume is properly mounted. 

Comment: @MarkB Puppeteer is trying to store Chrome's [user data directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md) into the volume. I have also used `aws ecs exec` to write content myself into the volume, but it does not persist either.

The content is written without any problem locally, but when I restart the container (or deploy a new one) there is no content in the mounted volume.